# Why is `std::this_thread::yield()` 10x slower than `std::this_thread::sleep_for(0s)`?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, scheduler

Just testing the two small programs,

```cpp
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(0s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the respective timings on my system (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, kernel version 5.19.0-43-generic),

```
./a.out  0,33s user 1,36s system 99% cpu 1,687 total
```

and:

```
./a.out  0,14s user 0,00s system 99% cpu 0,148 total
```

Why is `std::this_thread::yield()` 10x slower than `std::this_thread::sleep_for(0s)` ?

N.B. Timing is similar between g++ and clang++.

edit: As pointed out in the answer this is an optimization of the STL implementation, calling `sleep(0)` is in fact 300x slower (50us vs 150ns).

Comment: It is an implementation detail, but `sleep_for(x);` will typically do a single `if (x>0)` check, and then nothing if x is zero. Unlike yield() which as far as I understand will actually suspend the thread and give control back to OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the [source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/this_thread_sleep.h) for `this_thread::sleep_for`

```
template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
inline void
sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
{
    if (__rtime <= __rtime.zero())
      return;
    ...
```

So `sleep_for(0s)` does nothing, in fact your test program uses 0.0s of system time, basically an empty loop that runs entirely in user space (in fact I suspect that if you compile with optimizations, [it will be completely removed](https://godbolt.org/z/qsdecd8nb))

On the other hand, `yield` calls<sup>*</sup> [`sched_yield`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) which in turns will call `schedule()` in kernel space, thus at least executing some logic to check if there is another thread to schedule.

I believe that your 0.33s of user space time is basically syscall overhead.

<sup>* <sub>Actually jumps to [`__libcpp_thread_yield`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__threading_support) which then calls `sched_yield`, at least on linux</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, we don't even perform a system call. FYI, it seems calling the `sleep(0)` from `unistd.h` is much much slower.

Comment: Also once yielded the thread needs to wait until the OS schedules it again for its next run. Which also takes (wall) time